# How to use or emulate globalThis?

Tags: javascript

[globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) is a valid modern Javascript global property... But,

ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined

```
// is working when I declare here
//      var globalThis_MyBigcache=null;
// and replace globalThis.MyBigcache to globalThis_MyBigcache below

class myClass1 {
  constructor(x) {
    this.val=x
  }
  static createMany(a) {
    return a.map(x => new myClass1(x))
  }

  get y () {
    if (!globalThis.MyBigcache)
      globalThis.MyBigcache={a:11,b:22,"...":"..."} // big object
    return (globalThis.MyBigcache[this.val]===undefined)
         ? null
         : globalThis.MyBigcache[this.val]
  }
}
let b = myClass1.createMany(["a","b","c",1,2,3,"... many"])
console.log("-- item 2, myClass1:",b[1].y) // expected 22
```

I need a property that is not cloned by all class instances, need only one.

Comment: `s/globalThis/myClass1/`

Comment: @Paulpro YES, seems the answer! Is working, but, and the memory, how to avoid to clone the big object (or the y code) in all instances?

Comment: Browser support seems thin. On what platform are you testing this?

Comment: @Bergi I am using `node --experimental-modules test.mjs` at this moment, but supposing that is ES6 compliant... Hum... It is not ES6, [it is only a proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-global/#sec-other-properties-of-the-global-object-global)... So, I edited the question, now the @Paulpro suggestion can be an answer: it is fine for memory consuption? will be not generate `MyBigcache` clones (or `y` source-code clones) in the memory?

Comment: So yes, looks like it's *too* modern. But WTH do you need a global variable at all? Keep it local to your module, it's enough if you declare it outside of your class.

Comment: That will only create one object that is "shared" by all instances. It's the JavaScript analog of a static/class property.

Comment: @Paulpro, well, your last post (if no one say opposite)  is the final complement of the answer... Solved!